finding a bijective function from the borel sets onto power set of the natural numbers for a uncountable polish space.
In a second countable topological space $(X,\tau)$, I know that $|\tau| \leq |\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})| = 2^{\aleph_0}$ by considering a countable basis $U_n$ then by mapping open sets into the set of natural numbers that the open set contains for the countable basis. One can prove using transfinite induction that the borel sets equal union of $\Sigma_\alpha^0$ sets for $\alpha < \omega_1$(the first uncountable set). Due to by lack of understanding of cardinality, I am having trouble understanding why for an uncountable polish space why the borel sets would have the cardinality of $2^{\aleph_0}$

Here's an outline of a proof that there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ many Borel sets (in some fixed uncountable Polish space $X$) without using transfinite induction:

If $Y$ is a separable space, then there are $2^{\aleph_0}$-many continuous functions $Y\to X$. To see this, fix $D\subset Y$ countable and dense and consider the map $C(Y,X)\to X^D$ by $f\mapsto f|_D$. This is injective by continuity, and the codomain has size $|X^D|=(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}$.
If $A\subset X$ is Borel, then there exists a continuous map $f:\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}\to X$ with $f[\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}]=A$. For a proof, see Kechris' Classical Descriptive Set Theory, 13.7 p. 83.

Can you see how putting both things together gets you that there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ Borel subsets of $X$?

this makes complete sense, so from your thinking then this would imply that $|B(X)| \leq 2^{\aleph_0}$. Then would I just use the fact that the open sets in a polish space have the same cardinality as $2^{\aleph_0}$ to finish off the proof, or would there be a better way to think about this? Number 2 was perfect since I just finished reading about analytic sets. Also any good references to get a better understanding of set theory in particular for cardinality and ordinals? I am quite uncomfortable with these topics

@3jiwiojr3 Once you have $|\mathcal{B}(X)|\le 2^{\aleph_0}$, all you need to do is argue the opposite inequality. But this is easy: fix a countably infinite subset $Y$ of $X$. Every countable subset of $X$ is Borel, so $\mathcal{P}(Y)\subset \mathcal{B}(X)$ and $|\mathcal{P}(Y)|=2^{\aleph_0}$. As for a reference, you can check out Hrbacek-Jech's Introduction to Set Theory. I also like Kunen's The Foundations of Mathematics
